# sorting a list with python and changing int values based on location. is it possible using a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, while-loop

Given an int list, print a new list with double the length where its last element is the same as the original list, and all the other elements are 0. The original list will be length 1 or more.
4, 5, 6  -> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6

im having trouble firstly evaluating the int values in the list. tried through a while loop but had no luck, tried updating the position with a counter to move through the ints to print the entire list but still no luck.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
testList=[1,2,3,4]
buckets = []
for i in range(0,(len(testList)*2)-1):
    buckets.append(0)
buckets.append(testList[-1])
print(buckets)
```

i agree with you @Spangen, but I hope it's his first question ;)

Comment: haha im was getting annoyed with the question and couldn't even get the integers to preview me the int(input()) lists.

Comment: List=[1,2,3,4]
buckets = []
for i in range(0,(len(List))+1):
    buckets.append(0)
buckets.append(List[-1])
print(buckets)

Comment: this one seems to be correct in assigning the new values im just not too sure how to call on a list on integers in a pre-set program. should i use a loop and counter to reveal the list and allowing for the use of the program on a variety of different questions?

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: so with the question it has numerous inputs [1,2,5,6] [1,4,5,5,6,7] and so fourth and i was wondering how you have list = [int(input)] instead of list = [1,2,3,4]

Comment: just declare `testList=[]` and then using while loop
`i.append(input("a number please: "))`